# Problem creating an efficient stored procedure when querying a large number of rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get a list of the top customers across all suppliers to see which of our clients have the most orders. The problem is that we have such a large number of records that the stored procedure is taking too long to return the results.

Please help with any suggestions.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`rapidws`@`%` PROCEDURE `Rapidtrade`.`Question1`()
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_orders;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_orders Engine=Memory as(
    SELECT 
        a.AccountID AS Account,
        a.Name AS Customer_Name,
        COUNT(o.OrderID) AS TotalOrders,
        0 AS TotalActivities,
        0 AS SubTotal,
        0 AS MonthAgo
    FROM
        Account a
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        Orders o ON o.AccountID = a.AccountID
    WHERE
        o.CreateDate > TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, - 1, NOW())
    GROUP BY o.AccountID
    ORDER BY TotalOrders DESC
    LIMIT 20);

    SELECT * FROM temp_orders;
END
```

Comment: I see no point in using a sproc here. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Is your `on` clause indexed? and to simplify use `current_timestamp() - interval 1 hour` to compare.

Comment: I don't get the point of the RIGHT join. All orders should have accounts and if not you might as well ignore them for this purpose. And, yes, index needed on AccountID on orders table. I've also found using a subquery is sometimes faster than a join.

Comment: It is the beggining of A procedure that i am constructing where i join two temporary tables (Orders and Activities) and use the Total_Activities and Total_orders to determine the Top Accounts. That is the Goal of The procedure s to find out across So many Suppliers which are the Top Accounts Regardless of who the Supplier is.